# Python not finding local module folders

Tags: python

So I have a project that is layed out as followed:

```
.
└── project
    └── src
        ├── app.py
        └── connector
            ├── update.py
            └── connect.py
        └── transform
            └── dataframes.py
```

In the project, **app.py** imports from the **transform** module which imports from the **connector** module. However,**connector** is never found. I imagine this is due to the folder structure.

Does anyone know a work around for this?

Comment: can you show what did you do with the imports, so we can understand better the problem?

Comment: Did you add `__init__.py` files?

Comment: I was thinking that your description is a little bit confusing. What do you mean by saying app.py imports from the transform module? From the directory tree, they seem to be in the same level of hierarchy instead of from different ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is bit different than java. To identify a folder as a `module` you need to have empty `__init__.py` file inside that folder.

if that file is doesn't exist it is going to throw error that it's not able to find module.

Other options is use `pycharm` and rather than creating a folder, right click on choose `package`.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll try that, thank you!